# Sampling distribution

Tags: statistics

A random variable takes the values 1, 2, and 3, each with equal probability. List all possible samples of size two that may be chosen, without replacement, from this population and hence construct the sampling distribution of the sample mean.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What part or parts of the question are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I listed down all the possibilities already. But I don't know how to 'construct the sampling distribution of sample mean'.

Comment: Easy start: Determine the probability of selecting a first number and then a second number.  For sure, you should get all equal probabilities.

Comment: So, for each of the possible samples of size two, find the mean of the sample.  Then find the probability of having observed that sample.  This becomes your sampling distribution.  For example, if you get a sample $\{1, 3\}$, the mean of that sample is $2$, and the probability of observing $\{1, 3\}$ is...?  Then $\Pr[\bar X = 2] = \ldots$.

Comment: @Jollie : Questions posted here should not be phrased in a manner in which it is appropriate for an instructor to assign homework problems.  You should be asking a question, not passing on to us a question written by someone other than you, with no indication that you've thought about it.

Comment: So is the mean (1/3x1/2)/2 for all possible samples?What do u mean by the probability having observed that sample?

Comment: The sample mean is the mean of the sample.  So, if you draw a $1$ and then a $3$, you got the sample $\{1, 3\}$ and the mean of that sample is $(1+3)/2 = 2$.  The probability that you drew the sample $\{1, 3\}$ is $1/3$, because there are three possible samples of size two drawn without replacement:  $\{1, 2\}$, $\{1, 3\}$, $\{2, 3\}$, and each is equally likely because the individual probabilities of getting a $1$, $2$, or $3$ are equally likely.

Comment: Ok I understood already. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without replacement:
\begin{align}
1+2 & = 3 \\
1+3 & = 4 \\  \\
2+1 & = 3 \\
2+3 & = 5 \\  \\
3+1 & = 4 \\
3+2 & = 5
\end{align}

Sorting the sums into increasing order, you have: $\quad 3,3, \quad 4,4, \quad 5,5$

With replacement:
\begin{align}
1+1 & = 2 \\
1+2 & = 3 \\
1+3 & = 4 \\  \\
2+1 & = 3 \\
2+2 & = 4 \\
2+3 & = 5 \\  \\
3+1 & = 4 \\
3+2 & = 5 \\
3+3 & = 6
\end{align}

Sorting the sums into increasing order, you have: $\quad 2, \quad 3,3, \quad 4,4,4 \quad 5,5, \quad 6$

The sample mean for a sample of size $2$ is just half the *sum* of the observations in a sample.

(Of course, you should write the solution that you turn in the way I wrote what you see above, but this should tell you how to solve the problem.)

Comment: The sampling occurs **without replacement.**

Comment: I missed that.  Now I've edited my answer to include both.